# How to hint to C# that an implicit conversion exists?

Tags: c#, casting

I have a sequence of classes and interfaces as follows:

```cs
interface IA
{ }

class A : IA
{
    public static implicit operator A(int v) => new A(v);

    public A(int v)
    { ... }
}

class B
{
    public static void Foo(IA a)
    { ... }
}
```

And I want to be able to call `B.Foo(int)`.

`B.Foo(1)` does not compile, but `B.Foo((A)1)` does. I am able to call `B.Foo(1)` if the method signature is instead `Foo(A a)`, as C# is able to figure out the chain of implicit casting, so I know that I can modify the code in the following way:

```cs
class B
{
    public static void Foo(A a) => Foo((IA)a)
    public static void Foo(IA a)
    { ... }
}
```

However, this seems like a waste of code and time as I would have to do this for every method which accepts IA. It would become even more inefficient if a method such as `Bar(IA p1, IA p2, ...)` exists, as I would need n! copies of the signature with all of the different permutations of `A` and `IA`.

What is the best way to hint to C# that any method which accepts `IA` can also accept `int`?

Comment: Why would you expect that any class that implements that interface would have that implicit operator?

Comment: So... you are asking the compiler to search through _all_ the implementations of `IA` (there could be a lot of them, mind you) and find one that has an implicit conversion from `int`? The compiler is too lazy to do that.

Comment: @insane_developer That's a good point, but I'm not stating that all implementing classes have the operator, just that there exists an implicit cast to the interface from int. I understand why implicit operators aren't allowed within an interface

Comment: @Sweeper Absolutely, which is why I'm looking for a way to hint to the compiler that there exists an implicit cast, so that it doesn't have to search through all of the implementations

Comment: @SquareJAO And that's exactly what `B.Foo((A)1)` does! You are telling it "Just check if there is a conversion to `A`, and not any other implementations".

Comment: @Sweeper Yep, that makes complete sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a call like `B.Foo(1)`, the compiler would have to search through every type that implements `IA` to find a type `T` such that there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `T` and then perform the following conversion,

```
int -> T -> IA
```

The "finding `T`" step could be a lot of work, so the compiler is designed to *not do it*.

You seem to want to find a way to tell it that there is one specific implementation of `IA`, namely `A`, that does have have an implicit conversion from `int`. Well, you have actually already said it in the question:

```
B.Foo((A)1)
```

This tells the compiler to convert the `int` to an `A` first. Notice how this is as if you have found the type `T`, doing the hard work for the compiler.